# Where should I asked networking and computer operating systems questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Hey I have a questions related to networking and computer operating systems. So what is the best place to ask these question within the SE network.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than that.

Comment: Are you looking for network engineering? If so this is a pertinent place: [link](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Super-User if it's on you own computer.  Server-Fault if it's in a production environment, and stack overflow if it involves programming

Comment: Quite frankly, you're going to need to provide a little more detail or explanation to your intended question than "Security issue in windows 7" and "How to Restrict one ADMIN from accessing a folder of another ADMIN in windows 7" to have it be acceptable elsewhere on the SE network: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219659/security-issue-in-windows-7 . That's not a very descriptive title, and the body of the question wasn't even a full sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about general computing hardware and software are on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Questions on **professional** server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are on-topic on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: I have question about windows 7 Admin issue than where is the good place for this....

Comment: Frankly, if you aren't sure whether to ask on Server Fault and Super User, then Super User is almost always the right place